# How to get output of RAZOR template engine as a String and then write it to a file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASp.Net MVC 3 application, I am using the RAZOR engine for generating html with templates. It is working great for viewing in a browser. But I would like to get the output of the razor engine to a string and then write it to a file. For example:

**test.cshtml**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      @websiteTitle
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @websiteBody
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to make a call in my controller code like this:

```
String output = processTemplate(...)
//code to write 'output' to a file
```

..where `processTemplate()` takes the template file name and the required template parameters and produce the String output.

I [tried](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.net%20template%20engine&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=LKQhUaG9K4r8rAfT2YCYAw#hl=en&tbo=d&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net%20razor%20write%20to%20file&oq=asp.net%20razor%20write%20to%20file&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.467751.472196.1.472232.27.20.0.5.5.0.370.4392.0j6j12j1.19.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.R_G8UPgqEoU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.bmk&fp=ca85679e4aaec60f&biw=1280&bih=625) to [search in Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.net%20template%20engine&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=LKQhUaG9K4r8rAfT2YCYAw#hl=en&tbo=d&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net%20razor%20output%20to%20file&oq=asp.net%20razor%20output%20to%20file&gs_l=serp.3...10491.11156.2.11301.7.6.0.0.0.4.261.1204.0j3j3.6.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.hPfdOg5L4Ig&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.bmk&fp=ca85679e4aaec60f&biw=1280&bih=625) but couldn't find any docs on how to do it. Is it possible? If yes, how?

**Note:** I was able to do it using FreeMarker in Java web applications - we can output to Console, File or StringWriter. It was very convenient. I would like to have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "RazorEngine"

for an example of use, have a look at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackagesOfTheWeek12AccessingGoogleSpreadsheetsWithGDataFromCAndHostingRazorTemplatesToGenerateHTMLFromAConsoleApp.aspx

Comment: Thanks! The link is a good starting point. After hunting around a bit and struggling with 'Unable To Complile Template' exceptions, I finally got it working.

Comment: How did you load the razor template before parsing it? Is there a better method than simply loading from file using the `File` object?

Comment: you could get it from any source you want, depends on your application.